# Docker connection error from terminal : connection refused

Tags: linux, docker, error-handling, centos

I am using a centos 7 VM machine on a corporate device, whenever i try pulling an image from docker hub or even logging in to docker i get the following error

```html
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 44.207.96.114:443: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by restarting docker ?

```
sudo systemctl stop docker

sudo systemctl start docker
```

If it doesn't work, try docker commands with sudo